# Proof that function on topological space is continuous if and only if 2 restrictions of it are

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

[Topology such that function is continuous if and only if the restriction is.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497170/topology-such-that-function-is-continuous-if-and-only-if-the-restriction-is)

I've already seen this post but it didn't really help. The problem is the following:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $A,B$ subspaces in $X$ with $A\cup B =X$. Now assume that either $A$ and $B$ are both open OR $A$ nd $B$ are both closed. Let $f: X \to Y$ be an arbitrary function. I have to proof the following:

$f$ is continuous $\iff$ $f|_A$ and $f|_B$ are continuous.

Any ideas? (I think the  $\to $ direction is fairly simple since you know that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$ and then you can just put that into the condition of coninuity, but I'm not quite sure how to put it.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the lemma here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/359874 (part of a longer proof).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the case that $A$ and $B$ are open : If $U \subset Y$ is open, then $f^{-1}(U) = (f^{-1}(U) \cap A) \cup (f^{-1}(U) \cap B)$ which is open since the restrictions are continuous.

Comment: can you explain why $(f^{-1}(U) \cap A)$ is open? (i don't understand your argument why $(f^{-1}(U) \cap A) \cup (f^{-1}(U) \cap B)$ should be open. I know that preimages of continuous functions of open sets are open but how does this come into play here?)

Comment: You should notice that $f^{-1}(U) \cap A = g^{-1}(U)$ where $g: A \to Y$ is the restriction of $f$ to $A$.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually prove something a little bit more general:

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A_1$ and $A_2$ be subspaces of $X$. Let $g_{i}:A_i\rightarrow Y$ be continous for $i=1,2$. If $g_1$ and $g_2$ coincide on $A_1\cap A_2$ and $A_1$ and $A_2$ are either both open or both closed, then the function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ defined by $f(x)=g_1(x)$ if $x \in A_1$ and $f(x)=g_2(x)$ otherwise is continuous.

Assume that $g_1$ and $g_2$ are given continuous functions that satisfy the hypothesis and $A_1$ and $A_2$ are both open (respectively closed). Let $U$ be an open set (respectively closed set) of $Y$. Then, 
$$f^{-1}[U] = g_1^{-1}[U]\cup g_2^{-1}[U]$$ which is a binary union of open (respectively closed) sets in $X$, hence open (closed) by continuity of $g_i$ ($i=1,2$). Hence $f$ is continuous.